# Mumford-Tate groups of abelian surfaces

Tags: abelian-varieties, hodge-theory

For elliptic curves, one may easily compute Mumford-Tate groups; there are just two cases:

1) $E$ has no complex multiplication, and the Mumford-Tate group of $E$ is $GL_2$

2) $E$ has complex multiplication by a field $k$ and the Mumford-Tate group $E$ is a torus (of dimension two) in $GL_2$ induced by $k$.

In any case, the list of possible dimensions of Mumford-Tate groups of elliptic curves is $\{2,4\}$.

Is it possible to explicitly classify all the Mumford-Tate groups of abelian surfaces? What is the list of possible dimensions of Mumford-Tate groups in this case?

Comment: I think this is probably in Fite-Kedlaya-Rotger-Sutherland,
Sato-Tate distributions and Galois endomorphism modules in genus 2, https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6638. They classify Sato-Tate groups for abelian surfaces, and explain the relation to Mumford-Tate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of of all possible Hodge (special Mumford-Tate) groups of complex abelian varieties up to dimension 4 (and for simple abelian varieties up to dimension 5) is contained in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9901113.pdf https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002080050333 .

Comment: Thank you for this amazing reference. So, for instance, the Mumford-Tate group of an abelian surface with real multiplication is always of dimension 7? And for an abelian surface with quaternionic multiplication (split at $\infty$) it's always of dimension 4?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, that's correct.